# counting the number of sequences in which number $t$ should place after $(t+1)$ or $(t-1)$ appears except first number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can someone list the numbers $0,1, \ldots, n$ such that apart from the leading element, a number $t$ can be placed only if either $(t+1)$ or $(t-1)$ already appears?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** After the first step, the set of numbers-already-seen can grow only in $2$ places: at the bottom or at the top.